# strange behaviour with curl and python requests library

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

**I was trying to delete this question--but on a second thought I will just keep it--this is a live demo that as a developer I should pay more attention to details**

I am trying to get some data from a website. The requested url will take a look at the requested content type and then respond correspondingly.

So the curl command I tried:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36\r\n" http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/margin_bal_result.php\?l\=en-us\&d\=2016/11/15\&_\=1479700586981 -v
* About to connect() to www.tpex.org.tw port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 210.63.162.130... connected
> GET /web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/margin_bal_result.php?l=en-us&d=2016/11/15&_=1479700586981 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: www.tpex.org.tw
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 07:35:56 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-Cache: MISS from localhost
< X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
< Via: 1.0 localhost (squid/3.1.19)
< Connection: close
<
{"reportDate":"2016\/11\/15","iTotalRecords":610,"aaData":[["006201","YA HORNG ELECTRONIC CO.","6","0","0","0","6","0","0.09","6,361","0","0","0","0","0","0","0.0","6,361","0",""],...}
```

The response is truncated but basically it is JSON.

However, there is my Python code, I do not think there is much difference. But the response is html...

```
g_tpex_headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': (
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
        ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120'
        ' Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'
    ),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
data_link = (
    'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/'
    'margin_bal.php?l=en-us&d={}&_=1479700586981'
)
data = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = g_tpex_headers
    res = session.get(
        actual_data_link.format(target_dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
    )
    print(res.content[:400])
```

The log:

```
send: 'GET /web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/margin_bal.php?l=en-us&d=2016/11/18&_=1479700586981 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.tpex.org.tw\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nAccept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n'
```

and the response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title> HOME&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Mainboard&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Margin Trading&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Margin Balance</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/web/images/favicon.ic
```

I could not see much difference. So why python requests is not getting JSON response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paths where you are making the requests are different. In cURL command the final path component is `margin_bal_result.php` where as in Python script it is `margin_bal.php`. Once you change the path in Python script to match one in the cURL command you'll get JSON response.

**Update**: With cURL you need to specify the headers individually instead of adding them together. So in your example you should have used following command:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01" --header "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" --header "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36" http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/margin_bal_result.php\?l\=en-us\&d\=2016/11/15\&_\=1479700586981 -v > httpres.txt
```

Which would have resulted to following request being sent:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 210.63.162.130...
* Connected to www.tpex.org.tw (210.63.162.130) port 80 (#0)
> GET /web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/margin_bal_result.php?l=en-us&d=2016/11/15&_=1479700586981 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.tpex.org.tw
> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I was being so carelessssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: I have a question though, for curl, notice there is a row saying the User-Agent is curl--that line is not going to be sent to server right?

Comment: @JunchaoGu Updated result regarding cURL usage

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the request in python the same as in your curl totally.
your code:

```
data_link = (
    'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/'
    'margin_bal.php?l=en-us&d={}&_=1479700586981'
)
```

changed:

```
data_link = (
    'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/margin_trading/margin_balance/'
    'margin_bal_result.php?l=en-us&d={}&_=1479700586981'
)
```

After I corrected **data_link** , I found it works actually.

Comment: ...Do not think that is the key

Comment: @JunchaoGu That's the key as i promise. You use __margin_bal_result.php__ in curl but __margin_bal.php__ in python code.

Comment: @JunchaoGu if HTTP requests are the same then results are the same, it doesn't matter which library is used to make a request because remote website can't know that anyways. So the trick is always to make requests the same. There are tools like Wireshark which allows to inspect outgoing HTTP requests in a raw form, as they are sent.

Comment: I just found out this myself as well. I did not notice that issue!!! I thought they are the same. two hours wasted because of this. SUCH A STUPID ERROR. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I have a question though, for curl, notice there is a row saying the User-Agent is curl--that line is not going to be sent to server right?